# TS typed includes() in an array of string unions

Tags: typescript

Consider the object

```
type User = {
  uid: 'a' | 'b'
};

const user: User = {
   uid: 'a'
}
```

If I wanted to easily check for specific `uid`s I could do

```
["a", "b", "c"].includes(user.uid)
```

but in this case even though `"c"` isn't a valid string, TS won't catch it.

How would I tell the `includes` fn to check against an array of type `User["uid"]` here?

Answer (score 1):

I would approach the typing the other way around. You first need the IDs as a real object, otherwise you cannot easily do a run-time check against that.

```
const uids = ['a', 'b'] as const;

type User = {
  uid: typeof uids[number], // resolves to 'a' | 'b'
};

const user: User = {
   uid: 'a'
}

uids.includes(user.uid);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBArgSwCYRgXhgbQOQENsA0M2ARtgLoy6qiRQDcAsAFAtQCeADgKYwCqEbgCd0MAN4sY8ZAC4YHHiABm0lJjBwAtiWHkCLAL5NWzWtHiChcgcNETmU1XLzZDLFohQA6BGGAAbOCRuCAAKOEsvTwBKYyA)

To check against a specific subset, a new array variable can be declared:

```
type UID = typeof uids[number];
const subset: UID[] = ['a', 'b', 'x'];
subset.includes(user.uid);
```

Here an error would be shown for `'x'`, as that is not a valid ID. The `type` alias can help reduce duplication and improves readability.

Comment: Say there are 'a', 'b', and 'c'.  And I want to only check for 'a' & 'b',  how would that look then and will that be typed?

Comment: @Christian I expanded on that in the answer.